# Cerimoniale vs cerimonioso

Tags: word-usage

L'Oxford Dictionary da come prima definizione di ***[ceremonious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ceremonious)*** (come sinonimo di *cerimonial*) il significato di "related to grand and formal occasions" e solo come secondo significato indica quello legato ad un comportamento eccessivamente formale e complimentoso.

> - 1) Relating or appropriate to grand and formal occasions:
>     *a Great Hall where ceremonious and public appearances were made*
> - 2) Excessively polite; punctilious:
>     he accepted the gifts with ceremonious dignity

***Cerimonioso:***

> - In italiano l'aggettivo [cerimonioso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cerimonioso/) sembra essere usato unicamente in riferimento ad un comportamento eccessivamente complimentoso e affettato.
> - Mentre con riferimento al rito o alle occasioni solenni si usa ***[cerimoniale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/cerimoniale%20/)***.

Le mie domande:

È errato usare 'cerimonioso' al posto di 'cerimoniale' in qualsiasi caso?
Il "***ceremonious***" di "ceremonious and public appearance" a cui fa riferimento l'Oxford Dictionary come potrebbe essere correttamente tradotto in italiano?

Comment: Scusa, non ti sei risposto già da solo? “Cerimonioso” ha solo il secondo dei sensi che riporti per *ceremonious*. Come dice la voce Treccani a cui rimandi, «Di persona, che ama le cerimonie ..., che fa complimenti ... ; di cosa, fatta o detta per complimento, affettata, manierata».

Comment: @DaG - speravo di avere qualche informazione in più. Io penso che cerimoniale e cerimonioso siano stati  sinonimi e con il tempo il significato sia mutato, ad esempio.

Comment: Ah, d'accordo, capisco. A quel che trovo, anche la fonte lessicografica più antica a cui riesco a risalire, la 2ª edizione del Vocabolario della Crusca (1623), sembra dare per [cerimonioso](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?E=5316;-1381607964;&c1=350;-7;3;-21159276;212722725;&c2=129;-39;3;40;69;1;130;32;5;40;66;1;129;-39;65;-31;69;4;130;1025;5;40;75;13;130;27;3;1646876352;1545561153;&qi=&q1=cerimonioso&q2=&q3=&q4=&qr=null&num=20&o=115;-38489505;-1185594668;&idV=298880;5;-1550482490;-777671923;&TDE=cerimonioso) già solo il senso moderno (segue)

Comment: ...definendolo «Quegli che tratta con cerimonie.» ed esemplificando «C'è un'altra maniera di cerimoniose persone».

Comment: Cerimonioso non è sinonimo di "pomposo" nell'uso comune? Quantomeno mi pare che l'uso comune sia piuttosto negativo...

Answer (score 1):

"Cerimoniale" è anche aggettivo, ma credo che sia usato soprattutto (preferisco le tradizionali due t, come si usa ancora oggi in Toscana) come sostantivo. Mi sembra che "secondo il cerimoniale" sia più chiaro. 
Bisogna anche tenere presente che spesso "Cerimonioso" non è un complimento.

Answer (score 0):

Se in passato sono stati sinonimi non saprei.
Attualmente credo abbiano significati diversi:

Il **[cerimoniale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cerimoniale/)** (*ceremonial*) è l'insieme di regole e consuetudini che devono essere adottate e rispettate durante un cerimonia.

**[Cerimonioso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cerimonioso/)** (*ceremonious*) è un aggettivo usato con chi fa le cerimonie, nella sua accezione di fare complimenti, fare convenevoli.

Comment: Giusto, ma credo che Josh61 si riferisca in particolare a “cerimoniale” come aggettivo, dato che “cerimoniale” (agg.) e “cerimonioso” sono appunto i due significati dell'inglese *ceremonious*.

Comment: Non avevo colto la sfumatura, pensavo che la domanda fosse: È errato usare 'cerimonioso' al posto di 'cerimoniale' in qualsiasi caso?